# Border around reflection pass

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I am trying to set up a mix of live footage and 3d rendering, but I keep failing in obtaining a realistic reflection layer.

My workflow is to have a ground plane that is **totally white**, a **white sky**, and five the plane some degree of reflection (here in the screenshot it is 1.0, but it's only to show the problem, I know it's not realistic this way).
Then i multiply the reflection layer with the result of movieclip+foreground, but I keep having this annoying border around the plane.

How can I get rid of it?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, a **[Dilate/Erode](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Filter#Dilate.2FErode_Node)** node is commonly used to fix such issue.

Becides, it seems that you set the *robot* Layer as **Mask** layer for the *reflect* RenderLayer, which caused part of the plane was masked as transparent. Try untoggle that in RenderLayer setting, or add a new RenderLayer to get an expected alpha.

Comment: Hi @Leon, I've already tried that node but it seems to "erode" also the reflection itself, as they were some sort of semi-transparent alpha. Maybe I've got the connection of the nodes wrong?

Comment: @Cranio I've updated my answer.